# checkbox (click) angular 4 on dynamic checkbox creation

Tags: forms, angular, checkbox, dynamic

So I am dynamically creating checkboxes. What I want is for each checkbox to have a value which is dynamically created. On click of the checkbox I want the values of the checkbox to append to an array.

Here is what I am working on. Am I on track?

```
<div *ngFor="let cuisine of cuisines"
           class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 cuisineinput">

        <input type="checkbox"
               id="{{cuisine.cuisine}}"
               name="{{cuisine.cuisine}}"
               (click)="cuisineappend({{cuisine.cuisine}})"
               > {{cuisine.cuisine}}

      </div> <!--cuisine div -->
```

now Im getting an complaint on the  `(click)="cuisineappend({{cuisine.cuisine}})"` it doesn't like that I am passing`{{cuisine.cuisine}}` to the `cuisineappend` part. How would I pass the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<input type="checkbox"
               id="{{cuisine.cuisine}}"
               name="{{cuisine.cuisine}}"
               (click)="cuisineappend(cuisine.cuisine)"
               >
```

no need of `{{` brackets

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-smv4xr?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: I will, I had to wait for the time to pass so I could.